# The integral $\int J_0(x) \cos(x) dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, bessel-functions

I am trying to show that

$$ \int J_0(x) \cos(x) dx = x J_0 \cos(x) + x J_1 \sin(x) +C$$

where $J_n$ is the Bessel function of the first kind, using integration by parts. However, both obvious factors lead nowhere.

$$ \int J_0(x) \cos(x) dx = J_0 \sin(x) + \int \sin(x) J_1(x) dx + C$$

using $(J_0(x))'=-J_1(x)$. Also, the integral $\int J_0(x) dx$ is not known. Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: Write the integrand as $1\cdot \bigl( J_0(x)\cos x\bigr)$.

Comment: ...I suppose I'll have to use some recursive identity on $$J_0(x) \cos(x)$$ but I don't know any involving trigonometric functions..and $1=x^0$ leads to the same impasse I've reached above.

Comment: Do the integration by part as suggested above. Then use another integration by parts on the resulting $\int xJ_1\cos(x)$ term using the relation $\frac{d}{dx}[xJ_1] = xJ_0$. A more direct route is to take the derivative of the right hand side and show that it reduces to the integrand on the left hand side.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2235258/evaluate-the-following-integral) is a very similar question.

Comment: It is basically the same..thanks

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel Fischer pointed on the comment above, the integral can be computed as follows:

$\int J_o(x) \cos(x) dx=x J_0(x) \cos(x) + \int x J_1(x) \cos(x) dx + \int x J_0 \sin(x) dx +C= J_0(x) \cos(x) + \int x J_1(x) \cos(x) dx+x J_1(x)  \sin(x) - \int x J_1(x) \cos(x) dx$

which produces the desired result.